# Change , to . on input/tab

Tags: javascript

I'm making a form but for the sake of consistency I would like to change every `,` to an `.`

Is this possible with JavaScript, and if so how can I do this?

Comment: What type of element is this happening on? The whole page? A text box? Also are you using or willing to use jQuery?

Comment: Well im willing to use everything, and its pure for text boxes. And the best would be to have an script that only checkes textboxes with an certain id or class.

Comment: Edited my answer according to that comment

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regex at JavaScript for your purpose. Try that:

```
"your string".replace(/\,/g,'.'));
```

It will change all the occurrences of `,` with `.`

**PS:** You should add more information what kind of element of that as @Godwin mentioned.

Comment: your right my info was to little (monday morning wtf). Please check my comment on the first post.

Comment: You don't need to escape the comma, it's not a control char in regex.

Answer (score 0):

there are several ways. The easiest is to use regular expressions.

Just loop through all the values of your form like this (I'm assuming you only have one form on the page... if there are more, you'll need to do a nested loop to get through all of them).
Oh, and of course if you have periods in the values of your Submit button(s) you'll need to add exclusion for that, but I'm assuming you don't).

```
for(i=0; i<document.forms[0].elements.length; i++){
   document.forms[0].elements[i].value = document.forms[0].elements[i].value.replace(/,*/g, ".");
}
```

Comment: could you check my first post comment?

Comment: Not sure what else I can tell you. Unlike the other (correct) answer, I actually gave you the code to plug in that will alter the values in your form (as you have requested).  What else  is there to do but up-vote my answer and give me the green checkmark? I can't think of anything. :)

Comment: Well tbh I dont really understand ur code :). And as i said I would like an script which would only work on fields with an certain id or class. So if you could explain this (or put an example in http://jsfiddle.net/) I would with love up-vote ur answer!

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, you can do it fairly easily:

```
$('input[type="text"]')
.filter(
function () { 
return $(this).attr('class').match(/^yourclass$/);
}
)
.val(
function () {
return $(this).val().replace(/\,/g,'.');
}
);
```

Comment: You're joking right?  This unholy mess is what you describe as "fairly easily" for a problem that requires exactly 2 lines of 100% cross-browser backwards compatible code? You're including an entire bloated framework so that you can "only" use 8 lines to do what natively you can do in two?  The old adage about the hammer and the nail quickly come to mind.

Comment: I have to point out that yours is technically 3 lines, but who's counting? Also I spread it out for reading convenience, it would normally be on 1 line. >.> `$('input[type="text"]').filter(function () { return $(this).attr('class').match(/^yourclass$/)}).val(function () { return $(this).val().replace(/\,/g,'.')});`

Comment: And jQuery is for convenience. It's as simple as that.